# Trying to concatenate Html Textbox

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, concatenation

I'm trying to create one textbox that combines my two textbox fields (Rack and Row) into one.
This is my code:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Server.Rack, new { @class= "form-control" })

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Server.Row, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I'm trying to combine Server.Rack and Server.Row into the same textbox.  Is this possible in my code?

Comment: Use javascripts `onblur` to start a function when the mouse leaves the form control.  You could use the function to read both inputs and concat them into a new value to be displayed elsewhere.

Comment: I'm not the most experienced with code, could you give an example of what you're talking about?  thanks!

Comment: Do you want to do this on server or the client?

Comment: I updated my code. Please try this and let me know if it works...

Answer (score 0):

Your form:

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="input1" onblur="concat()"/>
<input type="text" id="input2" onblur="concat()"/>
</form>
<p id="concat"></p>
```

and the javascript:

```
function concat(){
  var x = document.getElementById('input1').innerHTML;
  var y = document.getElementById('input2').innerHTML;
  document.getElementById('concat').innerHTML = x.concat(y);
}
```

What this would do:
When the text boxes loose focus, the javascript would read the information in each textbox.  It would then print the results of BOTH textboxes (even if one is blank) into the `<p id="concat"></p>`.

Warning: This code was written quickly without checking for errors or any testing.  Review the code before using.

Additional info:  This is client side, not server side.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to concatenate these two properties in a ViewModel so that it can be used on different Views and cane be evaluated easily. What you should do is that create a ViewModel and add a new property called RackRow. Then set this property on your controller by concatenating Rack and Row properties and return it to the related View.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index_Read()
{            
    var result = repository.Server.Select(m => new
    Project.WebUI.Models.ServerViewModel
      {
          Rack = m.Rack,
          Row = m.Row,
          RackRow = m.Rack + " " + m.Row
      }
    );

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```